# SQLITE unwanted behavior on group_concat in query

Tags: sqlite, group-concat

I have two tables like this:

Fiddle: [click here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jXdhoe4McevzJoYZd24Nk/0)

My query:

```
select
f.id,
'{{' || group_concat(f.key||','||ifnull(f.value,'NULL'), '},{')||'}}' as 
key_value_pair_1,
'{{' || group_concat(r.key||','||ifnull(r.value,'NULL'), '},{')||'}}' as 
key_value_pair_2
FROM items_functions as f
LEFT JOIN items_functions_2 as r ON f.id = r.id
GROUP BY f.id
```

But this results into a strange behavior. All results where shown multiple times as you can see when you run the above linked fiddle.

But what I want is a result like this:

```
id      key_value_pair_1                   key_value_pair_2
214808  {{16,662},{17,808},{33,1},{60,2}}  {{16,662},{17,808},{33,1},{60,2}}
214809  {{16,902},{17,1103},{33,1},{60,2}} {{16,902},{17,1103},{33,1},{60,2}}
218965  {{19,808},{21,662},{33,1},{60,8}}  {{19,808},{21,662},{33,1},{60,8}}
218966  {{19,1103}{21,902},{33,1},{60,8}}  {{19,1103},{21,902},{33,1},{60,8}}
244574  {{16,999},{18,999},{54,174}}       {{16,999},{18,999},{54,174}}
```

I guess my query has to be adjusted. :)

Would be awesome, if anyone is happen to have a solution on this.

Thanks in advance!

Best regards,
Andreas

Comment: You should do group by before join.

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4jXdhoe4McevzJoYZd24Nk/1

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following will do what you want :-

```
SELECT 
    p1.id, p1.kvp1, p2.kvp2
    FROM
    (
        SELECT 
            id,
            '{{' || group_concat(key||','||ifnull(value,'NULL'), '},{')||'}}' 
            AS kvp1 
        FROM items_functions GROUP BY id
    ) 
    AS p1 
    JOIN 
            (
                SELECT 
                id,
                '{{' || group_concat(key||','||ifnull(value,'NULL'), '},{')||'}}'
                AS kvp2
                FROM items_functions_2 GROUP BY id
            ) 
    AS p2 
    ON p1.id = p2.id
```

Which produces :-

[image]